# Promisify QT callbacks to angularjs promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, qt, promise

I'm trying to write a promisify function that QT uses to an angularjs $q promise, but can't seem to get my head around it.

The QT promises are something like:

```
method(arg, arg, callback);
```

so if C++ had a method that would concatenate two strings the call would be:

```
method('A', 'B', function(result) {
  console.log(result);  //would print 'AB'
});
```

I'd like to be able to promisify this method so something like this would work:

```
var promiseMethod = $q.promisify(method);

promiseMethod('A', 'B')
  .then(result) {
     console.log(result);
  }
```

I started adding my decorator, but can't seem to get the actual method calls correct:

```
.config(function($provide) {
      $provide.decorator('$q', function($delegate, $rootScope) {
        $delegate.qtPromisify = function(fn) {

          /// ARGH!  what goes here!, this don't work.
          return function() {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            return $delegate(function(resolve, reject) {
              var result = fn.apply(null, args);
              resolve(result);
            });
          }
        };
        return $delegate;
      });
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work similar to an ES6 `Promise` promisify, so assuming your callback has the following signature: `function(error, result) {}` I can think of doing something like:

```
$delegate.qtPromisify = function(fn) {
    return function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        return $delegate(function(resolve, reject) {
            args.push(function(err, res) {
                    err ? reject(err) : resolve(res);
            });
            fn.apply(null, args);
        });
    };
};
```

Here we are just creating a callback that either resolves or rejects and pushing it to the `args` array, then using that array to call `apply`.

Or with ES6

```
$delegate.qtPromisify = function(fn) {
    return ([args]) => {
        return $delegate(function(resolve, reject) {
            const callback = (err, res) => (err ? reject(err) : resolve(res));

            fn.apply(null, [...args, callback]);
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.  I was getting lost int he see of callbacks and applies